# How can I retrieve a collection of nested entities depends on other rows of parent table using JPA in Spring Boot 3.0.6?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

stack: jpa, spring boot 3.0.6
I have an card entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "berserk_cards")
public class BerserkCard {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "set_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SetInfo setInfo;
```

and referenced to card set entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "sets")
public class SetInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private LocalDate release;
    private String name;
    private Boolean isStandard;
}
```

According to business logic cards with the same name can be drawn in different sets.
For example:

```
berserk_cards.name = cardname links with sets.name = set_1
berserk_cards.name = cardname links with sets.name = set_2
berserk_cards.name = cardname links with sets.name = set_3
```

I can get one card from db by id and can see cards set.
And now I want to get collection of set which contains set of all cards with same name.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "berserk_cards")
public class BerserkCard {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "set_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SetInfo setInfo;

    //How can i map it?
    private List<SetInfo> allSets;
```

Vanilla SQL example with correct result:

```
select * from  sets 
where id in (select set_id from berserk_cards where  name = 'cardname')
```

I tried to find solution in `@Formula` or `@ElementCollection` but both not working with entity.
Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to map with your 'allSets' List or what relationship this really is in the database/entity model. Your SQL though maps to JPQL most simply as: "Select s from BerserkCard b join b.setInfo s where b.name = :name". If BerserkCard's name is not unique, this should return a list of SetInfo instances. You shouldn't try to put that list into BerserkCard as it really isn't mapped to one single BerserkCard instance - they are mapped to multiple cards that just happen to have the same name. If you don't want or need multiple instances, map this instead as a OneToMany